# Loop over moving averages in Python

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I have the following data frame and I have to calculate the projection for this year and next year. For that, I multiply the average of the last 4 years by the average of the last 4 ratios.

The point is that I have to repeat the cycle for this year and next year.
I get to the final value but surely there's a much simpler way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":[2010,2011,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020],"PROFIT":[40,50,60,75,80,95,110,120,np.nan,np.nan]})

df['PROFIT_LOAG'] = df['PROFIT'].shift(1)
df['RATIO'] = round(df['PROFIT']/df['PROFIT_LOAG'],2)

df['PROF_AVG'] = df['PROFIT'].rolling(window=4).mean()
df['RATIO_AVG'] = df['RATIO'].rolling(window=4).mean()

#Last 2 values to predict
for i in range(8,10):

        df.loc[i,'PROFIT'] = df.loc[i-1,'PROF_AVG']*df.loc[i-1,'RATIO_AVG']
        new_prof= df['PROFIT'].rolling(window=4).mean()
        df.loc[i,'PROF_AVG'] = new_prof[i]
        new_ratio=df.loc[i,'PROFIT']/df.loc[i-1,'PROFIT']
        df.loc[i,'RATIO'] = new_ratio
        new_ratio_avg = df['RATIO'].rolling(window=4).mean()
        df.loc[i,'RATIO_AVG']=new_ratio_avg[i]
```

So, final output is:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":[2019,2020],"OUTPUT":[114.159375,120.530807]})
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar: I think he is just unsatisfied that the current working solution is not elegant.

Comment: at the risk of altering the problem statement, have you taken a look at other interpolation method that is [built-in in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) ?

Comment: The final output is to predict the two np.nan,np.nan. 114.159375 for 2019 and 120.530807 for 2020.

Comment: df_output = pd.DataFrame({"DATE":[2019,2020],"OUTPUT":
[114.159375,120.530807]})

Comment: `(df['PROFIT'].rolling(window=4, min_periods=2).mean() * df['RATIO'].rolling(window=4, min_periods=2).mean()).shift()`

Comment: well done scott!!!